# HeadSpace2 double title on homepage

Tags: title

I started using [HeadSpace2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/headspace2/), a meta plugin for WordPress, and it works great so far. I even managed to get the Google description that I wanted with it.

Let's call my website for "HomePage", and the head title is "Funny Stuff".
When people access the front page, it shows up as `HomePage | HomePage | Funny Stuff`.
If people click a link to a post, it says `Funny Stuff | HomePage`.

How do I fix so it only says `HomePage | Funny Stuff` and not `HomePage | HomePage | Funny Stuff`?

Comment: What theme do you use? Can you check the `header.php` for any special stuff when displaying the title? I believe Twenty Ten does something of its own on the front page that a plugin cannot catch, for example. (Use `@Jan` in your reply so I get a notification)

Comment: Check out the plugin *WordPress SEO by Yoast*: http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ It will sort out your <title> problems as well as on each post, gives you recommendations on keywords and what your Google SERP's listing will look like!

Answer (score 1):

In the theme's header.php look for the `<title>` tag. You'll probably find something like:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); wp_title(); ?></title>
```

The `wp_title()` function spits out the blog name now so you can just remove the `bloginfo()` bit.